# How to request a web page in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii2

In my site, there's a pervasive search bar that is a typeahead widget. The widget has a 'selected' callback that I am currently trying to implement.

In the callback, it determines whether or not it needs to make an AJAX request on the existing page or whether it needs to go to another page. My problem is that I cannot find anywhere a way to do a redirect with POSTed variables, like in a jQuery AJAX request. Is there any way to attain a page request with posted variables that will totally refresh the page, like clicking on a normal hyperlink?

Here is my code:

```
function getData(event, datum, dataset) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // get controller action portion of current url
    var Controller = '<?= preg_replace('/\/.*/', '', preg_replace('/\/.*\/web\//', '', Yii::$app->request->url)) ?>';
    var Key;
    // get key out of key-value pair - will either be 'game', 'developer' or 'publisher'
    for (var k in datum) {
        Key = k;
    }
    // if the controller action is the same as key, then the request is ajax
    // this works fine
    if (Key === Controller) {
        var req = $.ajax( {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'getchilddata',
            data: { data: datum[Key] },
            })
        .done(function(data) {
           $('#display-div').html(data);
        })
        .fail(function() {
           console.log("Failed");
        })
    } else { // else we need to go to a page on a different controller action according to Key
        // this is the best i've got so far but want it to be better
        window.location.href = Key + '/datastream?q=' + datum[Key];
    }
}
```

Comment: is it a page on the same domain?   are you using php at all?

Comment: @Anticom like the comment says above the ajax request, that bit works fine and isn't what I am asking about

Comment: @MichaelPodrybau Yes and yes.

Comment: Not totally clear what you are asking to do. What is the problem with the GET approach using query string?

Comment: Use header('Location: mypage.php');   You can store your POST data in a session variable and code in some checks to check if that session variable is set, set $_POST['whatever'] = $_SESSION['whatever'] and then unset($_SESSION['whatever']   (Yes, you can explicitly set $_POST variables this way)

Comment: @charlietfl Essentially I am asking if there's any way to add POST variables to window.location.href so that the query string isn't included in the url string.

Comment: not really, could create hidden form and submit that or do ajax that stores data in sesssion before redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve this is creating a form with hidden inputs, because you can't send post variables via Javascript, fortunately there is a [Jquery plugin](https://github.com/mgalante/jquery.redirect/blob/master/jquery.redirect.js) who will save you some code, but at the end the plugin just create a hidden form and simulate the redirect sending the form via POST, this is how to use it:

```
 if (Key === Controller) {
    $.ajax( {...})
 } else { 
    $().redirect(Key + '/datastream, {'q': 'datum[Key]'});
 }
```

Note: You can pass the method (GET or POST) as an optional third parameter, POST is the default

Comment: This is what I'm getting at. Could you advise on where to install the plugin?

Comment: @AndyHall just copy/paste the code in a js file and add it to your html after jquery, after that you will be ready to use it.

Comment: Selected you as the right answer as it's the most elegant solution

Comment: In fact is the only answer ;)

Comment: I'll just add this. As denoted in my tags, I'm using Yii 2. I was getting an issue with bad requests since I wasn't sending the _csrf value along with it in the post variables. I solved it by adding this to the post variables array:

_csrf: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content").

The only other way would have been to disable CSRF checking in the controller, which would be most distasteful.